# Ajax call returns current html page instead of requested file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have tried to make a ajax call using jquery like this: (file name is BR_states.txt and is correct matching)

```
<script>
function changeSelectedShippingCountry(select){
  var countryCode = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
  if (countryCode === 'AR' || countryCode === 'BR' ||
      countryCode === 'CA' || countryCode === 'IN' ||
      countryCode === 'IT' || countryCode === 'JP' ||
      countryCode === 'MX' || countryCode === 'NL' ||
      countryCode === 'TH' || countryCode === 'US') {
      var urlToFile = countryCode + "_states.txt";
      $.ajax({
        url: urlToFile,
        error: function() {
            alert('error ajax');
         },
         dataType: 'text',
         success: function(data){
            alert(data);
            var stateCells = document.getElementsByClassName('stateCells');
            stateCells[0].style.display = "table-cell";
            stateCells[1].style.display = "table-cell";
            var options = data.split(/\n/);
            $('select[name="state"]').html('');
            for (i=0; i<options.length; i++) {
                var optionKeyVal = options[i].split('=');
                $('select[name="state"]').html('<option value="'+ optionkeyVal[0] +'">'+ optionKeyVal[1] +'</option>');
            }
         }
      });
  } else {
      var stateCells = document.getElementsByClassName('stateCells');
      stateCells[0].style.display = "hidden";
      stateCells[1].style.display = "hidden";
  } 
}
</script>
```

But i allways get the current html page back as a response. I have tried to put the text file directly under the Webcontent folder and in also under the src folder in the Java Resources folder. Where is it accessible?

I have also problem loading javascript files into  tags.

I use Apache tiles. Can that be a problem?

Structure:

WebContent
 -tiles
 -META-INF
 -WEB-INF
 -layouts
 BR_states.txt

Comment: Share your `countryCode` variable code too and share your full code..!

Comment: Your code should work properly if your path to your requested file is correct..!

Comment: You see in `function (data)` ,You get everything from your requested file in that `data` variable and then you are alerting that data so what's the problem then..! If you are not getting what you should be getting then it means there is something wrong with your path to the requested file..!

Comment: Can you share a live link to your file where you are having this code??

Comment: try accessing the url directly to see if it is correct.

Comment: It sounds like requesting `CA_states.txt` results in your server returning the HTML response instead of the JSON you expect. I would check your server configuration to see if it routes your request to the correct handler and try again.

Comment: How do I check the server configuration?

Comment: When I try to access the url directly like http://localhost:8080/RetailStore/BR_states.txt it just redirect to http://localhost:8080/RetailStore/products

Answer (score 0):

OK, I solved the problem. It was due to the servlet mapping to @WebServlet("/") which caused my root to be redirected to whatever that servlet redirected to, which was /products. So, I never had a chance to access the root where a put my javascript and BR_states.txt files.